# Connection failed in QuteCom SIP client

Tags: sip, voip, sip-server, kamailio

I have chosen QuteCom SIP client for windows to chat.I have installed and configured the account with my public server. My SIP server is kamailio.The connection to the server is not established. The application is connecting to the server for a long time.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If looks like keep connecting, then I guess the SIP messages don't get to the server.

You can install Wireshark to monitor traffic on windows host on port 5060 (the SIP port) in order to see if SIP messages are sent to the server.

On server, you can install ngrep for the purpose of seeing if traffic from the phone comes there. The command would be like:

```
ngrep -d any -qt -W byline port 5060
```

If you don't see traffic coming to the SIP server, then might be a firewall or an ALG between the client and the server, or, a firewall even on client host or server itself.

If it is something in between (not on client host or server), then you should try to use TCP or better TLS.

Note that if you have the firewall on the server, you will see the SIP packets coming on the network, but they will be dropped by the kernel before getting to application layer. Typically on Linux you can see the firewall rules with:

```
iptables -L
```

If the SIP packets come to the server, then set debug=3 in kamailio.cfg, restart kamailio and watch the syslog file (e.g., /var/log/syslog or /var/log/messgaes) for kamailio-specific debug messages -- you should get hints of what happens during processing.